# No output when using matches regex

Tags: c#, regex, match

I have no output after the `Match m = Regex.Match`. I think there is a issue with it. Can someone please check the code, if it ok.

The input `alarm_text` looks like:

> Prio 1 WESTERSTRAAT 140 ENKHUIZEN Woning brand 4632 4651

What I wanted to do is splitting the string in four groups: "Prio 1", "WESTERSTRAAT 140 ENKHUIZEN", "Woning brand", "4632 4651"

```
 using System;
 using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
 using System.Data.Odbc;

 namespace pdw_db
 {
    internal class pdw_db
    {
        public pdw_db()
        {
        }

        private static void databaseThis(string capcode, string melding, string korps, string streetName, string preText, string postText, string cars)
        {
                string[] strArray = new string[] { "insert into alarmeringen2010(capcode, desc1, department, melding, alerting, data1, voertuigen)values('", capcode, "','", melding, "','", korps, "','", streetName, "','", preText, "','", postText, "','", cars, "',);" };
                string str = string.Concat(strArray);

                OdbcConnection odbcConnection = new OdbcConnection("DSN=pdw_db");
                try
                {
                    OdbcCommand odbcCommand = new OdbcCommand(str, odbcConnection);
                    odbcConnection.Open();
                    OdbcDataReader odbcDataReader = odbcCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    while (odbcDataReader.Read())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(odbcDataReader.GetString(0));
                    }
                    odbcDataReader.Close();
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (odbcConnection != null)
                    {
                        odbcConnection.Dispose();
                    }
                }

        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 2)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                string alarm_capcode, alarm_text, alarm_korps;

                //kill qoutes in alarmering
                args[1] = args[1].Replace("\"", "");
                args[1] = args[1].Replace("\'", "");
                args[1] = args[1].Replace("'", "");
                args[2] = args[2].Replace("\"", "");
                args[2] = args[2].Replace("\'", "");
                args[2] = args[2].Replace("'", "");

                alarm_capcode = args[0];
                alarm_text = args[1];
                alarm_korps = args[2];

                Match m = Regex.Match(alarm_text, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]+.[A-Z])(.*\s)([0-9].*\s)");

                string preText = m.Groups[1].Value;
                string streetName = m.Groups[2].Value;
                string postText = m.Groups[3].Value;
                string cars = m.Groups[4].Value;

                databaseThis(alarm_capcode, alarm_text, alarm_korps, streetName, preText, postText, cars);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you showing us so much not relevant code? Just provide input text, desired output and code with Regex.

Comment: Can you describe how the text should be split up in words? It's hard to tell from your regex the actual pattern you're looking for.

Comment: preText = Prio 1  
streetName = WESTERSTRAAT 140 ENKHUIZEN  
postText = Woning brand  
cars = 4632 4651

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 4th group - without `[0-9]+` or `[0-9].*` your last group lacks your last numer:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(alarm_text, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]+.[A-Z])(.*\s)([0-9].*\s[0-9]+)");
```

Of course it also depends if you have only numbers in your last group.
There is also an error in your second group - without `+\s` text goes to group 3 - now it should be ok

```
Match m = Regex.Match(alarm_text, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]+.[A-Z]+\s)(.*\s)([0-9].*\s[0-9].*)");
```

Comment: thnx for your help, but i don't see any data in my database.

Comment: @user1307010 As I run in debug mode the code above (second version), it splits the text you provided into four groups. Have you checked it how it looks like in debug? In my case three first groups have space at the end, but I do not know if it fits you. Maybe there is something wrong when you prepare your alarm_text?

Comment: yes your right, the output is right. So the issue is the prepare... but i can't find the issue.

Comment: @user1307010 Maybe your strArray should look like this:             string[] strArray = new string[] { "insert into alarmeringen2010(capcode, desc1, department, melding, alerting, data1, voertuigen)values('", capcode, "','", melding, "','", korps, "','", streetName, "','", preText, "','", postText, "','", cars, "');" };
- without last comma

Comment: @user1307010 and if (args.Length > 2) shouldn't be if (args.Length > 3)? As you are using then args[2].

Answer (score 0):

Got the code almost working.  Only he is taking plane value text. not the string

```
private static void databaseThis(string capcode, string melding, string korps)
        {
            Match m = Regex.Match(melding, @"(.*\s)([A-Z]+.[0-9]+.[A-Z]+\s)(.*\s)([0-9].*\s[0-9].*)");
            string preText = m.Groups[1].Value;
            string streetName = m.Groups[2].Value;
            string postText = m.Groups[3].Value;
            string cars = m.Groups[4].Value;

            string[] strArray = new string[] { "insert into alarmeringen2010(capcode, desc1, department, melding, alerting, data1, voertuigen)values('capcode','melding','korps','streetName','preText','postText','cars');" };
            string str = string.Concat(strArray);
          }
```